# Coordinate geometry prove

Tags: coordinate-systems

Prove that the diagonals of a rectangle bisect each other and are equal ( using coordinate geometry ). How to do this sum?

Answer (score 1):

### Hint

**Take the vertices as $(0,0), (a,0), (a,b), (b,0)$ where $a$ and $b$ are the length and breadth of the rectangle.**

**Does it help you?**

Comment: Thanx a lot sir I got it now I can do the sum

Comment: 1. I am not 'sir' 2. You are welcome!